# HQL Sessions in java

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

How can I get user by login in my database through the Session??
UserDAO

```
public UserDataSet getUDSLogin(String login)  {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT id FROM UserDataSet ");
        List<UserDataSet> uds = query.list();
        query.setParameterList("login", uds); //get user by login

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        //Restrictions.eq("login", login).getValue();
        //session.getTransaction().rollback();
        session.close();
        return (UserDataSet) uds;
    }
```

Comment: You do know this code does not make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

This just not make sence

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT id FROM UserDataSet ");
    List<UserDataSet> uds = query.list(); // you get all user ids
    query.setParameterList("login", uds); // you set non-existent parameter to query that already have been ran
```

moreover, transactions are not needed here.

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT id FROM UserDataSet uds WHERE uds.login:=login");
query.setParameter("login",login);
usersWithGivenLogin=query.list();
```

just change `uds.login` to whatever column name it is in `UserDataSet`

Comment: usersWithGivenLogin is a variable? what type?

Comment: List of something. You tell me of what it is.